# Meaning of 'with one answering present' in describing a result of vote

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following sentence is from [the New York Times article.](https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEMyu3nCFBEePOPpXk2ra--kqFwgEKg8IACoHCAowjuuKAzCWrzww9oEY?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen) What does the italic phrase mean?

> “The yeas are 223 and the nays are 207, *with one answering present.* ...

I guess that the voting limit time had passed but one congressman was still voting in the box with the intention of resisting the agenda. That would mean abstention.

Am I right?

Comment: I doubt the NYT writer seriously expects many of his readers to be aware of the procedural convention in Congress votes whereby "**Present**" is the response recorded by any potential voters who wish to explicitly ***abstain***. But *in context*, when we've already been told that everyone else voted either "**Yea**" or "**Nay**" (also by convention, since otherwise we'd expect "**Yes**" and "**No**" today), the meaning of the third possible response is so obvious there's no need for the article to spell it out. Just sayin'...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's primarily about Congressional procedures, not really the use or learning of English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No time limit had passed. When a member of the US congress is asked to vote for a bill or resolution, three answers are possible - 'yea' (I vote for the bill) 'nay' (I vote against the bill) and 'present' (I abstain from voting). Consider the last to mean 'I am present'.

> Members may abstain from voting on a measure because of a personal
> or pecuniary interest in the measure being considered and thus
> announce an intention to be recorded as ``present'' on the issue.

[[House Practice: A Guide to the Rules, Precedents and Procedures of the House]
[Chapter 58. Voting]](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-HPRACTICE-112/html/GPO-HPRACTICE-112-59.htm)